# How to make %s in python a changing variable

Tags: python, sql, csv

I am writing a program that takes information from a CSV file and writes it into a SQL database. I am getting a different number of parameters to write in for a different number of SQL columns per file.

For example one person could give me a file with the parameters:

```
(color:green, length:100, width:200)
```

which would require a statement like:

```
(Insert Into XYZ (color,length,width) Values(%s,%s,%s), (color_variable, length_variable, width_variable)
```

But another person could give me only the parameter thickness which would result in:

```
(Insert INTO XYZ (thickness) Values(%s), (thickness_variable)
```

How would I make it so that the number of `%s` values I have is a variable that can change with the number of arguments in the CSV file

Comment: Check the arguments first and then decide what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Based in your example I will assume your SQL database allows all fields to be null.

In that case, you should do a generic statement inserting ALL fields to the DB, so you can insert the ones provided by the user, and keep the others NULL.

```
(Insert Into XYZ (color,length,width, thickness) Values(%s,%s,%s, %s), (color_variable, length_variable, width_variable, thickness)
```

Then you just define all as NULL but the ones your user provides.